# Get Facebook user profile picture from name

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an website where people had filled in their username, like firstname.lastname . Then I showed their Facebook profile picture on my website as avatar. But as everyone knows I can't use graph.facebook.com/firstname.lastname, is there a solution which can convert the username into the uid or something else without having the people to login?

I hope someone can help me because I can't find it.
Thanks!

Comment: There could be 1000s of people with the same first and last names, so this will not be enough to get an individuals profile picture.

Comment: I mean they filled in their username, it could be firstname.lastname or something different, mark zuckerberg uses "mark". When you go to facebook.com/ name you see your profile. In the graph API 1 you could go to graph.facebook.com/ name but that is not possible anymore, there are sites where you can convert your name to uid but I can't find how it's done with the API.

Comment: Why cant you use their API?

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/username should allow you to get what you need. Some users have reported some issues with this though, but there are workarounds

Comment: It is not possible any more via API, Facebook has removed the `username` field with v2.0, and does not allow looking up user via it any more. All sites that still offer this are not using the API, but scrape facebook.com pages, which is of course against ToS (unless you get explicit prior written permission from Facebook.)

Comment: So it's not possible at all? Unless they change their username into their uid

Comment: Use Facebook Login to get the user id